# Get constant feedback from bash process, java

Tags: java, linux, bash

To execute process/command in bash from java one can use the following class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CmdExecutor {
    public CmdExecutor(){

    }
    public void exe(String [] args) throws IOException{
            if (args.length <= 0) {
                System.out.println("empty command");
                return;
            }

           Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
           InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
           InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

           String line;
           System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
              Arrays.toString(args));

           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
           }
    }
}
```

However. What if the process don't terminate(yet). It does calculations and output it in the shell. I want to be able to run the process in another thread and get changes in the output, like frame by frame strings. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

You may want to have one thread (producer) reading process output, and putting them into a LinkedBlockingQueue (`queue.put`), then have another thread (consumer) to get elements from the queue (`queue.poll`) and process it.